# How to catch if my camera resolution has not changed?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, webcam

I want to try to set some exotic resolutions on my web-camera device. like 100x1000 or some standart. I need to find out if my camera supports desired resolution. Howto get such info using OpenCV? (because it seems to me that my try-catch around cvSetCaptureProperty does not work, while that function does not return anething usefull)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a cvGetCaptureProperty? If so, what does it return after you set the resolution?